# ANTconfiguration not shown in jenkins

Tags: tomcat, jenkins

I am new to jenkins setup.I got some error while run in the tomcat server.but jenkins is open  but when i need to configure system(Manage jenkins-->configure system),I am able to configure java but i am not able to configure ANT.I already installed my ant in local and put it in a system path and its work fine in locally.I am try to use many plugins realted to ant in jenkins that time also not able to get ant configure in configure system.Kindly tell me what i have to for fix this issue and how to use ant in jenkins.

And my next question is why this much of error comes when run it in tomcat but its open.

My error is

```
SEVERE: Failed Loading plugin maven-plugin
java.io.IOException: Unable to load hudson.maven.PluginImpl from maven-plugin
    at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.load(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:3...

Jan 27, 2014 2:06:51 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onTaskFailed
SEVERE: Failed Loading plugin email-ext
java.io.IOException: Dependency maven-plugin (1.409) doesn't exist
    at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:487)...

Jan 27, 2014 2:06:51 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Prepared all plugins
Jan 27, 2014 2:06:52 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started all plugins
Jan 27, 2014 2:06:52 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Augmented all extensions
Jan 27, 2014 2:07:03 PM hudson.ExtensionFinder$GuiceFinder$FaultTolerantScope$1 error
WARNING: Failed to instantiate Key[type=hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher$DescriptorImpl, annotation=[none]]; skipping this component
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/cloudbees/jenkins/plugins/sshcredentials/impl/BasicSSHUserPrivateKey$PrivateKeySource
  at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher$DescriptorImpl.<init>(Unknown Source).... com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:52)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:65)
    voke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)...
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/cloudbees/jenkins/plugins/sshcredentials/impl/BasicSSHUserPrivateKey$PrivateKeySource
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey$PrivateKeySource
    at .....
```

I am using jenkins 1.548 war.Kindly help me to fix this issue,Thanks

Comment: Looks like an improperly installed Jenkins server. I'm assuming this is the Jenkins application log file, not a build error log.